# Integral Elements OF Finite Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have the following lemma, with proof:

> Let $A$ be integrally closed. Let $B$ be a field. Then an element $b\in B$ is integral over $A$ iff the monic polynomial $f_b(X)\in F[X]$ over the field of fractions $F$, of $A$, has coefficients in $A$.
>
> $Proof:$ Let $L$ be a finite extension of $F$ which contains $B$ and all $\sigma(b)$, for all $F$-homomorphisms from $B$ to an algebraically closed field $C$. Since $b \in L$ is integral over $A, \sigma(b)\in L$ is also integral over $A$ for all $\sigma$. Then $f_b(X) = \prod (X-\sigma(b))$ has coefficients in >$F$ which belong to the ring generated by $A$ and $\sigma(b)$ and therefore are integral over $A$. Since $A$ is integrally closed, $f_b(X) \in A[X]$. The reverse implication is trivial.

From this, I understand that we use $B$ and all the $\sigma(b)$ to construct $L$ in such a manner that $f_b(X)$ factorises into linear products. I understand the coefficients of this product are then in $F$ by the assumption on $f_b(X)$.

But I do not understand how the conclusion "...[these coefficients] belong to the ring generated by $A$ and $\sigma(b)$ and therefore are integral over $A$. Since $A$ is integrally closed, $f_b(X) \in A[X]$" is then drawn. Since these coefficients are strictly generated by products and sums of the $\sigma(b)$'s, I am at a loss as for where the mention of $A$ comes from. And the closing sentence seemingly springs from nowhere. Could someone offer some clarification?

I have been reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory in tandem with the source of this lemma, and I realise [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292638/an-element-is-integral-iff-its-minimal-polynomial-has-integral-coefficients) question is completely equivalent. But in my minds eye I just cannot arrange it into a way that satisfies the issue I have above.

Comment: Is what's tripping up that the product of two elements that are integral over $A$ is also integral over $A$?

Comment: No, I don't understand why you can claim that the coefficients of $\prod (X-\sigma (b))$ are generated by $\sigma(b) \space \textbf{and} \space A$. Where has $A$ come from? These coefficients will be generated purely as products and sums of $\sigma(b)$.

Comment: ah, I see what you're saying.  Somehow I didn't even notice that, but I understand your complaint.  I believe what they're trying to say is:  the coefficients are in the ring generated over $A$ by the $\sigma(b)$.  Since the $\sigma(b)$ are all integral over $A$, the whole ring is integral over $A$, so the coefficients are integral over $A$.

Comment: So I think I've got it, just tell me if I'm wrong. So because all the $\sigma(b)$ are integral over $A$, the ring generated by $A$ and all the $\sigma(b)$ will be integral over $A$ (standard fact), and then because the coefficients will be elements of this ring, they will also be integral over $A$. However, it is known the coefficients are elements of $F$. Hence, as they are elements of $F$ and integral, they must be elements of $A$, as $A$ is integrally closed.

Comment: That sounds good to me.