# Doubt about a paragraph in the book "Algebraic Number Theory by Neukirch".

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Please refer to the question in the given link.

The question already has an answer here

[An element is integral iff its minimal polynomial has integral coefficients.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292638/an-element-is-integral-iff-its-minimal-polynomial-has-integral-coefficients/292649#292649)

My question is ---

Here, $A$ is integrally closed in $K$. And $\beta_i$'s $\in \bar{K}$. Don't we have to show that $\beta_i$'s $\in K$ to show they belong to $A$? Because $A$ is integrally closed in $K$ not in $\bar{K}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $\beta_i$'s belong to $\bar{K}$ which are integral over $A$. So, coefficients of $p(x)$ are integral over $A$. But the coefficients of $p(x)$ belong to $K$. So, coefficients of $p(x)$ belong to $A$ as $A$ is integrally closed in $K$. Hence, $p(x)\in A[x]$.